# What does table rows under Info table in mysql workbench indicate?

Tags: mysql

[image]

When clicking on info for a particular table in mysql workbench, there is a parameter called table rows that has a number beside it. It does not match up to the number of records that are actually in the table, nor does it sync to the actual count after clicking on Analyze Table to update potentially outdated parameters. What does this indicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the value from the `num_rows` column in `information_schema.tables` (or from  `information_schema.innondb_sys_tablestats`.)

That's an *estimate* of the number of rows in the table; this is used by the optimizer when evaluating probable cost (performance) of possible execution plans.

For InnoDB, statistics are collected using a sampling technique, a random deep dive into a number of pages; results from the sampled pages is extrapolated to the entire table.

Again, `num_rows` is *not* intended to be an accurate count of the number of rows in the table; its an estimated value which is used by the optimizer.

See MySQL Reference Manual `ANALYZE TABLE`, and InnoDB statistics gathering.

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-performance-optimizer-statistics.html